# static function in template class: gcc vs VS

Tags: c++

The following c++ code compiles and works with Visual Studio 2017, but gives error "expected primary-expression before '>' token" with gcc 5.0.  Any idea why?  Description is a struct, and Description::add is a function template.

```
template <class X>
struct DataPoint
{
    X value;

    DataPoint()
    : value(0.) {}

    DataPoint( X value )
    : value(value) {}

    static void describe(Description< DataPoint<X> > & desc)
    {
        desc.add<X>("f", ".", offsetof(DataPoint<X>, value));
    }
}
```

In fact VS doesn't even complain when the DataPoint template type is not specified:

```
static void describe(Description<DataPoint> & desc)
{
    desc.add<X>("f", ".", offsetof(DataPoint, value));
}
```

Comment: `DataPoint` (without supplying template arguments) is the *injected-class-name*

Comment: different lexical parsers interpret non-standard things differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not standard C++.  The `add` in `desc.add<X>` is a dependent name, so the compiler doesn't know if it is a template.  Visual C++ still doesn't implement the entire two-phase lookup, so it's not surprising that it lets this through.  But g++ (and clang, etc) require you to use the `template` keyword.

```
desc.template add<X>("f", ".", offsetof(DataPoint, value));
```

Comment: Thanks!  My code now compiles on both windows and POSIX.